# Printing out an object of array's members error

Tags: c++, arrays, string, printing

I'm having a little bit of trouble printing out a member of my struct. This is what I have so far:

```
struct Code
{
  char letter;
  string sequence;
}

void createCode(HuffmanNode *root, string codestr, Code *codeBook, int count)
{
  if(root->getRight() == NULL && root->getLeft() == NULL)
  {
    Code code;
    code.letter = root->getLetter();
    code.sequence = codestr;
    codeBook[count] = code;
    count++;
  }
  else
  {
    createCode(root->getLeft(), codestr + "1", codeBook, count);
    createCode(root->getRight(), codestr + "0", codeBook, count);
  }
}
```

This works all fine, but in main when I try to print out the member sequence in my array of Codes in Codebook:

```
string codestr;
count = 0;
Code codeBook[256];
createCode(root, string codestr, codeBook, count); //root is already created 
for(int i = 256; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if(isalpha(codeBook[i].letter))
  cout << codeBook[i].sequence << " ";
}
```

Only the last string I stored is printed. Might anyone know a fix and why this is happening? If anyone could help, that'd be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `createCode`, `count` is not incrementing, because you are passing it by value, change to pass by reference:

```
void createCode(HuffmanNode *root, string codestr, Code *codeBook, int& count)
```

array codeBook contains 256 elements but index is from 0 to 255. for loop should be:

```
for(int i = 255; i >= 0; i--)
```

Otherwise access out-of-boundry array element is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I just fixed that but it still didn't print out correctly...  any other tips?

Comment: you shall pass count to createCode by reference

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that `createCode()` is always passed `count=0`. Because of this, you store all `Code` entries at the zeroth position in your array, and the last one overwrites all previous entries.

To fix, either pass `count` by reference or pointer, or make the function return the new value of `count`.

Finally, the starting value of the `for` loop is out of bounds (off by one).

Comment: Well when I call createCode() count is incremented in my if statement isnt it?

Comment: @user200081: Not really. You increment it in the first branch, and recursively call createCreate() in the second. You never do both.

Comment: Ah that helped. Thank you! I understand what I did wrong now. I need to pass by reference...